# Get TCP port number from struct tcp_sock

Tags: linux, tcp, linux-kernel

How can I get the TCP port number of a `tcp_sock` structure in the Linux kernel?  The instance of `tcp_sock` is in the context of `tcp_recvmsg()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tcp_recvmsg()`, the `struct tcp_sock` object is derived from parameter `struct sock sk`.  You can do `inet_sk(sk)->inet_sport` to get the **destination port** of the TCP packet.  `inet_sk(sk)->inet_dport` should get the source port of the packet.

Answer (score 0):

Use `htons((unsigned short int)inet_sk(sk)->inet_sport)` and `htons((unsigned short int)inet_sk(sk)->inet_dport)` to get ports as per `wireshark` port

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This basically duplicates the accepted answer, adding a call to `htons` without explanation. IMO this does not add anything without explanation why this is better than the accepted answer.